# Password is revealed on Leanback Guided Step Action when clicked

Tags: android, leanback

I have a GuidedStepFragment as an authentication-type fragment in my leanback application.

How do I keep a "password" GuidedAction from revealing the typed-text when the user presses enter or goes to the next Guided Action?

The issue I'm facing is the password is hidden while the user is typing, **but revealed when the user goes to the next GuidedAction**.

```
@Override
public void onCreateActions(@NonNull List<GuidedAction> actions, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GuidedAction action;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        type = getArguments().getInt(ARG_TYPE);
    }
    if (type == TYPE_EMAIL) {
        action = new GuidedAction.Builder(getActivity())
                .id(ActionConstants.ACTION_INPUT_EMAIL)
                .editable(true)
                .description(getString(R.string.email_address_hint))
                .editInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                .build();
    } else {
        action = new GuidedAction.Builder(getActivity())
                .id(ActionConstants.ACTION_INPUT_PASS)
                .editable(true)
                .description(getString(R.string.password))
                .editInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
                .build();
    }
    actions.add(action);
    action = new GuidedAction.Builder(getActivity())
            .id(ActionConstants.ACTION_CONTINUE)
            .title(R.string.next)
            .hasNext(true) // Shows the small arrow indicating there's something next...
            .build();
    actions.add(action);
}
```

I have tried overriding setupImeOptions to explicitly set the TransformationMethod on the EditText, but that still doesn't keep the user's password hidden after the user goes to the next Action.

```
@Override
protected void setupImeOptions(ViewHolder vh, GuidedAction action) {
    switch ((int) action.getId()) {
        case ActionConstants.ACTION_INPUT_PASS :
            vh.getEditableDescriptionView().setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
            vh.getEditableTitleView().setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
            break;
    }
    super.setupImeOptions(vh, action);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/GuidedStepFragment,  GuidedStepFragment is deprecated class, i think you need to upgrade to  GuidedStepSupportFragment

Comment: @AkashDubey I'm pretty sure I gave that a try and had the same results, but I'll try again to confirm and report back here.

Comment: @dell116 did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code works

```
GuidedAction.Builder(activity)
            .id(PASSWORD.toLong())
            .title("Password")
            .descriptionEditable(true)
            .descriptionInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
            .descriptionEditInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
            .build()
```